# Is it possible to simulate xbox one controller inputs to control your xbox wirelessly?

Tags: python, wireless, xbox-one

I am making a python script that interacts with Kodi on my raspberry pi to control it with my standard tv remote and I was wondering, could I also control my Xbox with it? I am assuming it can be done as you can already use the Xbox controller on your computer so you should be able to do it in reverse with Bluetooth.

If someone could briefly go over a possible way to do this that would be great. (And preferably in python 3.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found a library that should work: https://pypi.org/project/xbox-smartglass-core/

This library allows you to do any function you can do in the Xbox smart-glass app on your phone or on the Xbox companion app for windows. One of those features is sending keypresses.